# Function returning BLANK in DAX

Tags: variables, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

I have written a DAX code that checks whether a campaign has been filtered and if it has it basically gets the previous campaign year and then the function should return the total sales for the previous year campaign but its just returning blank.

```
testing = 
VAR extractCampaignYear = IF (ISFILTERED('Campaign Overview'[campaign]),MIN('Campaign Overview'[previousExtractedYear]),0)

RETURN

SUMX(
FILTER(
    SUMMARIZE (
    'Campaign Overview',
    'Campaign Overview'[campaign],
    "extractedCampaign",TRIM(MIN('Campaign Overview'[extractedCampaignName])),
    "campaignYear", MIN('Campaign Overview'[extractedYearFromCampaign]),
    "Sales", SUM ( 'Campaign Overview'[sales] )
),
[campaignYear] = extractCampaignYear), [Sales])
```

However, when I remove the `extractCampaignYear` and make it `[campaignYear] = 2022` for example, it works.

Does anyone know why the `campaignYear` and `extractCampaignYear` are not matching up?

**When using a variable:**

[image]

**When I explicitly type `2022`:**
[image]

Comment: (ISFILTERED('Campaign Overview'[campaign]) is probably returning zero as it is being evaluated in a context where the column is NOT being filtered.

Comment: The column is being filtered, I have campaign name column as a slicer and selected a name, it then retrieves the name year from the campaign name and -1 to get the previous year for that campaign

Comment: Can you share the .pbix?

Comment: Is extractCampaignYear  definitely returning 2022?

Comment: Yes I removed the sumx and just did return extractCampaignYear and it returns 2022. I also double checked both columns and they are both the same datatype Whole Number. I will see if I can send a sanitised pbix

Comment: How should I share the pbix file with you?

Comment: Upload to an external site and update your question with the link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255837/discussion-between-jcoke-and-davide-bacci).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
testing =
VAR extractCampaignYear = IF (ISFILTERED('Campaign Overview'[campaign]),MIN('Campaign Overview'[previousExtractedYear]),0)

RETURN
CALCULATE(
SUMX(
FILTER(
SUMMARIZE (
'Campaign Overview',
'Campaign Overview'[campaign],
"extractedCampaign",TRIM(MIN('Campaign Overview'[extractedCampaignName])),
"campaignYear", MIN('Campaign Overview'[extractedYearFromCampaign]),
"Sales", SUM ( 'Campaign Overview'[sales] )
),
[campaignYear] = extractCampaignYear), [Sales]),
REMOVEFILTERS()
)
```

When you select a value from the slicer, you're filtering your table and hence 2023 is filter so when you then look for 2022, you get zero records.

FYI, I haven't fixed your summarise code but you should NOT create new columns using summarise - use ADDCOLUMNS() instead to avoid weird issues that will be impossible to debug.